# How to use the result of a query as liquibase defaultValueComputed?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, function, liquibase

Working with liquibase I've found that it's possible to define properties, and use them as defaultValue for columns.

Everything is ok if you use pre-made functions, but how to do when you have some custom SQL that produces some data, to be used in the same manner?

I tried to do something like this:

```xml
<property name="myFunc" value="SELECT CURRENT_DATE + time '08:00:00' + (random() * interval '3 hours')::time" dbms="postgresql"/>

...

<column name="selected_pickup_date" type="datetime" defaultValueComputed="${myFunc}" remarks="Selected from customer during order creation">
         <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
```

But it didn't work! The error code showed that liquibase was just placing my SQL string as the column's default value.

SQL wasn't parsed as I expected.

How to proceed to get the query result used as default value?

Answer (score 3):

After many attempts, I understood that Liquibase doesn't parse SQL in properties, probably it only executes functions and places their result in the property value, and the placeholder ${xxx} is replaced with the function's output.

Once a new row is added to the table, and the column with defaultValue is empty, the property value is read and used in place of `NULL`.

I tried many solutions and luckily the last one worked:

1. Take the SQL and create a new function in a sql file, in my case it was simple:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fixed_date_rand_time;

CREATE FUNCTION fixed_date_rand_time() RETURNS timestamp
AS $$ SELECT CURRENT_DATE + time '08:00:00' + (random() * interval '3 hours')::time $$
          LANGUAGE SQL;
```

1. Import the sql before other changelogs

```xml
 <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="func.sql" />
```

2. Now..you can create the property! This time calling the function instead of the SQL string

```xml
    <property name="myFunc" value="fixed_date_rand_time()" dbms="postgresql"/>

...

    <changeSet id="20201026174848-1" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="my_table">

            <column name="selected_pickup_date" type="datetime" defaultValueComputed="${myFunc}" remarks="Selected from customer during order creation">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

...
```

**Et Voilà! It works now!**

The very-nice thing is that properties can be used with `context` too, allowing you to bypass the new function when outside of local test environment:

```xml
 <property name="myFunc" value="fixed_date_rand_time()" dbms="postgresql" context="test"/>

 <property name="myFunc" value="NULL" dbms="postgresql" context="!test"/>
```

Not perfect, it works only with nullable columns, but there must a solution.

Finally the database is loaded with correct values automatically, taking away the hassle of updating dates everyday, to have everything work as expected.

I hope that this solution can help somebody, who maybe has the will to refine it a bit :-)

My Liquibase version is 3.10, I cannot update to the latest due to other dependencies... maybe the problem has been addressed there.

I don't exclude that the feature has been disabled intentionally in favour of the pro version.

Have a nice day

Comment: I am aware that this is not the hot question after two years.
I am afraid that your assumption _"...probably it only executes functions and places their result in the property value, and the placeholder ${xxx} is replaced with the function's output."_ is not correct. 

Liquibase simply inlines the function call into the command 
defaultValueComputed="${myFunc}"

So the resulting "column" tag will be something like

<column name="selected_pickup_date" type="datetime" defaultValueComputed="fixed_date_rand_time()" remarks="Selected from customer during order creation">

Comment: Hi @FeketeKamosh, thanks for your reply... As you said this answer has its time, I cannot remember exactly what leaded me to that conclusion. If I still remember something, the problem was related to the impossbility to define `defaultValueComputed` directly from a SQL snippet/function, defined into liquibase config (see OP question). Defining the function in the external file worked as exepcted. I didn't explain well my idea probably. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, it is likely hard to define function as the property value. The liquibase property is not evaluated, it is simply a placeholder for the String.
What I wanted to say is that your property "myFunc" is simply a placeholder for either the text "fixed_date_rand_time()" or text "null". This text is luckily evaluated in the syntax defaultValueComputed="${myFunc}". 
But for sure the "myFunc" property does not hold the result value of the (in fact not called) function.
Anyway thank you for you solution, that inspired me with my use case.

Comment: Glad that it helped you somehow. I'm pretty sure that with the configuration above you can define a custom function to your database instance, and recall it later in a computed value. I'm not working anymore on this project, if I will have the chance to test this again, I'll add the result here. Cheers